# Find lines with first word containing a certain set of letters

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression, pcre

The input file exists out of lines containing multiple 10-letter combinations:

```
NGNAEAREAX EAHVSELYCI FNWGNLACQM AWKLRMDHIT PRYMFNYMVM
NCNREDEEEQ EAHVSELYCI FNWGNLACQM AWKLRMDHIT PRYMFNYMVM
```

I need a regex (PCRE or BRE/ERE) that finds all lines of which the first word contains the letters to form the word "REGEX". So the first word of the line has to contain at least 1 R, 2 E's, 1 G and 1 X.

So the output of the above would be:

```
NGNAEAREAX EAHVSELYCI FNWGNLACQM AWKLRMDHIT PRYMFNYMVM
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @NasirRiley I've tried '^.?.?.?.?.?([SATN].?.?){5,} .*' but I don't think doing it that way is viable.

Comment: What exact commands including the syntax did you try? What was the output including any error messages? Add all of this information to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't(*) match this with a single regex.  You need to test each condition (one R, two Es, one G, one X) separately and logically AND them together to get a final true or false result.

e.g. using `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /R/ && $1 ~ /E.*E/ && $1 ~ /G/ && $1 ~ /X/' inputfile.txt 
NGNAEAREAX EAHVSELYCI FNWGNLACQM AWKLRMDHIT PRYMFNYMVM
```

(*) well, you could create a regex containing alternations for **every** possible combination of those five letters (R, E, G, E again, and X) appearing in different order but that isn't practical.

---

BTW, if you need case-insensitive matches and you're using GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '$1 ~ /R/ && $1 ~ /E.*E/ && $1 ~ /G/ && $1 ~ /X/' inputfile.txt
```

or case-insensitive without GNU awk:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /[Rr]/ && $1 ~ /[Ee].*[Ee]/ && $1 ~ /[Gg]/ && $1 ~ /[Xx]/' inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'for lines() {my %h; for .words.[0].comb() { %h{$_}++ };  \
           .put if %h.keys.contains( "R" & "E" & "G" & "X") && %h<E> >= 2 };'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
NGNAEAREAX EAHVSELYCI FNWGNLACQM AWKLRMDHIT PRYMFNYMVM
NCNREDEEEQ EAHVSELYCI FNWGNLACQM AWKLRMDHIT PRYMFNYMVM
```

Sample Output:

```
NGNAEAREAX EAHVSELYCI FNWGNLACQM AWKLRMDHIT PRYMFNYMVM
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. The problem as posted really seems to be a key/value problem, for which Raku is well suited (notice: no regex in the solution).

Briefly, `lines` are read-in, each line is broken on whitespace with `words`, and the first word `[0]` is taken. This first word is `comb`ed into individual letters.

From this point each letter is fed into the (previously declared) `%h` hash, whereupon the letter (represented by topic variable `$_`) immediately becomes a unique `key` in the hash, with a value determined by the number of times that `key` has been seen (hence the `%h{$_}++` plus-plus).

Returning the `%h` hash at this point in the code ( using `say %h.sort` ), you would see the following:

```perl
(A => 3 E => 2 G => 1 N => 2 R => 1 X => 1)
(C => 1 D => 1 E => 4 N => 2 Q => 1 R => 1)
```

The final statement of the code solution at top demands that the `%h` hash `contains` each letter `"R" & "E" & "G" & "X"` as keys, and also that the value of the hash's "`E`" key is `>= 2`. If found, the entire line is returned (`.put` being short for `$_.put`, wherein `$_` represents the input line).

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-5-to-6/08-junctions.html
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use look ahead operators for that:

```
grep -P '^\s*+(?=\S*R)(?=\S*E\S*E)(?=\S*G)(?=\S*X)'
```

Here looking for:

- `^` match at the start of the line
- `\s*+` skipping (and not looking back) all leading whitespace if any
- `(?=\S*R)` look ahead at this spot for a `R` following any number of non-whitespace character.
- `(?=\S*E\S*E)` look ahead at the same spot for non-whitespaces`E`non-whitespaces`E`.
- you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's `awk` with a function that calculates the character counts of any word and that uses that function first to process the query word ("REGEX") and then each of the words from the first field of the input.  It then checks whether the counts of characters in the 1st field word are enough to generate the query word and if so, the word is printed.

```bash
awk -v word="REGEX" '
    function calc(w,a) {
        for (i = 1; i <= length(w); ++i) a[substr(w,i,1)]++
    }
    BEGIN {
        # Character frequencies of the query word are stored in q.
        calc(word,q)
    }
    {
        # Get character frequencies for $1 and see if any
        # frequency in q are higher. If so, next.
        delete f; calc($1,f)
        for (ch in q) if (f[ch] < q[ch]) next
        print $1
    }' file
```

Running this on the input in the question would output `NGNAEAREAX`.

The only inefficiency here is that we calculate the frequencies of characters that we're uninterested in.